# error with zeller's congruence code

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the month (1-12):");
    int month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the day (1-31):");
    int day = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the year (ex. 2014):");
    int year = input.nextInt();

    if (month == 1)
        month = 13;
    else if (month == 2)
        month = 14;

    int Zeller = day + ((26 * (month + 1)) / 10) + year +
        (year / 4) + (6 * (year / 100)) + (year / 400);

    int dayofweek = (Zeller + 5) % 7 + 1;

     if (dayofweek == 1)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Monday");
    else if (dayofweek == 2)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Tuesday");
    else if (dayofweek == 3)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Wednesday");
    else if (dayofweek == 4)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Thursday");
    else if (dayofweek == 5)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Friday");
    else if (dayofweek == 6)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Saturday");
    else if (dayofweek == 7)
        System.out.print("Day of the week: Sunday");  
}
```

The code wont calculate the dates in Jan and Feb correctly. It is always a day or two off.

For example: If I enter `Jan 1, 2010` the code should output `Day of the week: Friday`, but instead, its saying its `Day of the week: Saturday`.

I've checked my calculations couldn't find any error.

Comment: I'm scared of `year/100`, `year/400`, and the other integer divisions.

Comment: what should i do here? declare a new interger?

Comment: When you say you've "checked your calculations" were you doing integer division?  If that term doesn't mean anything to you, that's likely the root of your bug.

Comment: should i calculate the formula separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Zeller's congruence wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller's_congruence), when you adjust the January and February months, you must also adjust the year down, because the algorithm relies on January and February being considered the "13th" and "14th" months of the previous year.

> But when using a computer, it is simpler to handle the modified year Y, which is Y - 1 during January and February:

Add the year adjustment code to your January and February cases.

```
if (month == 1)
{
    month = 13;
    year--;  // add this
}
else if (month == 2)
{
    month = 14;
    year--;  // add this
}
```

Output for your test case of January 1st, 2010:

```
Enter the month (1-12):1
Enter the day (1-31):1
Enter the year (ex. 2014):2010
Day of the week: Friday
```

The cases above could be simplified:

```
if (month == 1 || month == 2)
{
    month += 12;
    year--;
}
```

Comment: February 29, 2008
January 17, 2015  July 4, 1776 those dates are still not produced

Comment: February 29th, 2008 was a Friday.  January 17, 2015 will be a Saturday.  July 4, 1776 was a Thursday.  My copy of your program, with my changes, gets these correct.

Comment: i made those changes but still wouldnt give me the right dates.

Comment: basically now i get those results, but when i submit it to the program that checks the code, it tells me its not producing those 3 dates.